# Execute a katalon test suite using Jenkins account on a different server

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, web-testing, katalon-studio

I've created a test suite using Katalon-Studio and managed to execute it via Jenkins on my personal computer (localhost).

Is there a way to run my Katalon test suite using a Jenkins account that isn't on localhost? I mean, all my tests are stored in Github, is there a way to configure a Jenkins account **on a different server** to pull my katalon test suite from Github and execute it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a solution for your problem, just follow:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows

and

https://www.katalon.com/videos/jenkins-master-slave-configuration/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It means that I will use my computer as a master though no? Is there a way to do this without involving my computer at all?

Comment: You need to have a Jenkins Server (not on your computer) and your Slave Client (or many), you can configure your Jenkins Job to copy Workspace from Git to Slave Workspace, and then you can run the Job.

Comment: I tried to follow the guide you sent but I'm not sure how to fill in the fields. For instance, what should I write in the remote root directory field? or in the launch method field. These kind of staff are quite new to me